# Missing encryption key to decrypt a file. RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails c

Tags: deployment, capistrano, ruby-on-rails-7, ruby-2.7

I tried deploying a ruby on rails app using capistrano and i'm currently having an issue with production env keys. It says Missing encryption key to decrypt file with. Ask your team for your master key and write it to config/credentials/production.key or put it in the ENV['RAILS_MASTER_KEY'].  I have secrets.yml file containing

```
development:
  secret_key_base:xxxx

test:
  secret_key_base: xxxx


production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

I also have a master.key but don't have  production.key. i do have production.yml.enc though. I am new to this and i don't know what did i do wrong here.

I deleted and created a whole new credentials.yml.enc and master.key  and it works in test and development environment but not in production.

Comment: Have you read [the guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#environmental-security)?

Comment: @smathy I did read the guide, but I found out the problem was not there it was just my encryption and decryption for production were not working properly but it got solved. Thanks for the help.